# Как правильно писать названия улиц с прилагательным?

Tags: топонимика

**Советская улица** или **улица Советская**?
**Широкий переулок** или **переулок Широкий**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае единственного прилагательного в названии улицы слово "улица" входит в это название и согласуется с прилагательным обычным образом, т.е. без инверсии. Форма записи официального наименования улицы может изменяться при включении в алфавитный список, но случая с прилагательным это не затрагивает (уникальная часть названия начинается с него). На примере такого списка можно увидеть, что в случаях, когда полное название топонима действительно начинается с "улицы" (напр. имени человека), в конец записи через запятую переносится слово "улица (проспект)", и на основании этой запятой в сложных случаях можно обратной перестановкой точно восстановить наименование.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_улиц_Москвы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B)

В некоторых канцелярских документах (типа полицейских протоколов и отчётов) сложилась практика разделять видовое наименование и уникальную часть названия улицы, что может приводить недоразумениям при восстановлении некоторых типов названий улиц. Например, название "Карташихина улица" (по имени Карташихи) в протоколе может фигурировать как "ДТП на ул. Карташихина". Если из такого протокола восстановить название улицы, то ничто не мешает предположить, будто это "улица Карташихина" (имени человека по фамилии Карташихин). Из-за подобных канцеляризмов некоторые недоразумения закрепились (Большая Зелейная улица -> улица Б. Зеленина). Любопытно, что такой приём ведомственной формализации не обладает универсальностью: ещё никому в голову не приходило переиначить для протокола Большой проспект, составив фразу "на проспекте Большой" или сказать "на линии Косая (линии 18)", "на протоке Шкиперский" и т.п.
Здравый смысл подсказывает не применять подобных перестановок слов на картах. Если что-то и можно изменять в названии улицы, так это добавлять для пояснения само слово "улица", если оно не входит в название (ул. Крещатик и т.п.).

Answer (score 3):

Если название оформлено как полное прилагательное, то существуют два варианта его употребления в речи:

1) **официально-деловой стиль, официальные ситуации**: название не склоняется и находится после родового наименования: ДТП произошло на улице Советская;

2) **разговорный, художественный и публицистический стиль**: название склоняется и находится  в препозиции: встретимся на Советской улице.

Материал взят из "Практической стилистики современного русского языка", РАН, 2012 год.

На обычных картах (на Яндексе, например) пишется: Большая Тульская улица, Духовской переулок.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал с этим особо не заморачиваться... Во всем виновата компьютеризация. Вот если в форме название стоит первым, то будет у вас *Невский пр.*, что выглядит хорошо. Но будет также и *Гривцова пер.*, что выглядит не очень. Что поделаешь...
Но вручную вы так, естественно, не напишете. А в ваших примерах, думаю, что оба варианта допустимы. Единственно, чтоб не путали имя собственное с нарицательным, я бы писал *переулок Широкий*.

Comment: «Гривцова переулок» это точно не по-русски. Я спрашивал про прилагательные, а тут его нет.
После долгих исследований сделал вывод, что нарушать естественный порядок слов недопустимо. Так как могут встретиться такие названия, где порядок важен и меняет смысл самого названия. Улица Жукова и Жукова улица — две реальные разные улицы в Питере. Или Баранов переулок или переулок Баранов. Первый вариант правильный, а второй звучит вульгарно и легко можно получить по лицу, если жителям сказать что они живут в переулке Баранов.

Answer (score 0):

Как на карте написано, так и писать. Обычно "улица" стоит перед названием, а "переулки", "проспекты" и пр. - после.

Comment: Но я карты рисую, поэтому и спрашиваю. С краткими притяжательными прилагательными всё просто. Там от порядка зависит смысл названия и его склонение. Улицу Репищева не спутаешь с Репищевой улицей. С обычными прилагательными больше нравится естественный порядок, там и как склонять становится понятно. Но насколько корректна инверсия? И склоняется ли название при инверсии?

Comment: _Sergey Kuznetsov:  Но **я карты рисую, поэтому и спрашиваю**. С краткими притяжательными прилагательными всё просто. Там от порядка зависит смысл названия и его склонение. Улицу Репищева не спутаешь с Репищевой улицей... Но **насколько корректна инверсия?**_  === Ни на сколько. На картах на первом месте должно располагаться имя собственное: _**Репищева** ул., **Репищевая** ул._

Comment: Не всегда на первом месте должно быть название. Например, улица кого-то (Ленина, Хачатуряна и т. д.) или улица Раменки (реки, р. п.).

Comment: Название улицы это единое целое и недопустимо резать его на части и перетасовывать. Если назвали улицу 3-ей улицей Строителей, то так и надо писать и говорить. Никакого смысла нет выдёргивать слово улица и куда-то переставлять. Тут нюанс в том, что само слово «улица» имеет два смысла. Это и синоним слова дорога, и часть названия этой дороги. Видимо поэтому многим хочется поставить его вперёд. Так конечно можно, но не стоит коверкать само полное название.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. Вообще вам надо консультироваться у топонимистов в каждом конкретном случае, здесь только общие советы будут. Если найду какие-то связи старые - выложу координаты. У меня, кажется, где-то адрес был одного такого человека. Если найду, поделюсь - или ему сам напишу.
А мой адрес - в профиле.

Вопрос Вы правильно ставите. Инверсия тут не всегда корректна. Но современные справочники часто этого не учитывают. В первом приближении можно считать, что названия, образованные не от имен собственных - как ваши Советская, Широкий - инверсию такую допускают без искажения смысла и без потери возможности найти адрес в кадастре или справочнике. Практический смысл как раз в этом, не потерять возможность поиска, остальное уже - сфера ответственности краеведов, ошибка неприятна, но не критична.

А вот с именами типа "Михайловская" или там "Пушкинская" лучше не экспериментировать. Поищите в интернете полный справочник всех улиц/переулков и т. д. РФ - им и пользуйтесь. Такие справочники уже лет пятнадцать в свободном доступе есть, для унификации написания всяких бухгалтерских и кадровых систем типа 1с. Если там нет указания на порядок слов, то инверсия допустима. Как-то так. Если чего наврал - не ругайте сильно.

Comment: К сожалению многие реестры названий улиц грешат полным пренебрежением к этим самым названиям. В Москве и Санкт-Петербурге ответственно подошли к этому вопросу и оговаривают порядок слов. Но в администрациях большинства городов даже не задумываются об этом и клепают реестры как попало, даже часто опуская слово улица в таблицах, либо ставят вперёд везде без разбору. Вот и гадай потом как правильно.